# order of evaluation of arguments to a constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have this class:

```
struct A
{
  A(int, int, int) {}
};
```

and I initialize it like this:

```
A{ a(), b(), c() };
```

Where the functions `a()`, `b()` and `c()` all return `int`. Should `a()` be called before `b()` and `b()` before `c()`?

I am mystified by the following paragraph from the standard (8.5.4 [dcl.init.list] p4):

> Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack
>   expansions (14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear. That is, every value computation and
>   side effect associated with a given initializer-clause is sequenced before every value computation and side
>   effect associated with any initializer-clause that follows it in the comma-separated list of the initializer-list.
>   [ Note: This evaluation ordering holds regardless of the semantics of the initialization; for example, it applies
>   when the elements of the initializer-list are interpreted as arguments of a constructor call, even though
>   ordinarily there are no sequencing constraints on the arguments of a call. — end note ]

According to the quote, the functions would be called in order they appear, but when I've tested this with my compiler (g++-4.8.1), it did not hold. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Thanks, taking an initializer list in the constructor appears to be the workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [bug in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253) (thanks to [Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381573/order-of-evaluation-of-arguments-to-a-constructor/17381687?noredirect=1#comment25231543_17381687) for the link). The paragraph you quoted applies in general to list initialization, where the terms are defined pretty clearly in paragraph 8.5.4/1:

> *List-initialization* is initialization of an object or reference from a *braced-init-list*. Such an initializer is
>   called an *initializer list*, and the comma-separated *initializer-clauses* of the list are called the *elements* of the
>   initializer list.

There is no reason to believe this should apply only to the invocation of an initializer list constructor. Also, the note in the paragraph you quoted clarifies that:

> **This evaluation ordering** holds regardless of the semantics of the initialization; for example, it **applies when the elements of the initializer-list are interpreted as arguments of a constructor call**, even though ordinarily there are no sequencing constraints on the arguments of a call.

Comment: This is [GCC bug 51253](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253).

Answer (score 2):

Be careful what you're dealing with. The quote you are quoting, as far as I can see, holds only for *initializer lists*. The feature you are using is *uniform initialization*. It is required for initializer lists, but I doubt it is for uniform initialization.

Comment: The quote does mention constructor calls. Do you think the quote is relevant only for constructors taking initializer lists?

Comment: Uniform initialization is an informal term for the grammatical construct known as a braced-init-list. Which is different from the type `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: And the quoted text begins with "Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list"